# Android Toggle Spinner

Tags: android, android-widget, toggle

I want to implement a toggle button in the form of a spinner (or slot machine). Basically it will consist of a large rectangle with the text OFF on it and when the user clicks on it, the words ON are animated onto the rectangle instead of off. Is there an easy way to do this or do you know of a widget which can do this please

**WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR**

I have two images, each one of them represent the state that the toggle button can be in (i.e. ON and OFF). I then created a drawable XML file:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/on" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/on" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/off" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/off" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="false"/>

</selector>
```

Then I set the background of the `ToggleButton` to the XML drawable:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON " />
```

[image]

Comment: could you please show us some of your efforts?

Answer (score 1):

if you want change the state of button programmatically, you need use the method `setChecked` on the toggle button

```
// Declare button
private ToggleButton myButton;
...   
// Initialise button
myButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
...
// Sets button text as "OFF" and "ON"
myButton.setText("OFF");
myButton.setText("ON");
myButton.setChecked(false);
...
// Set an on click listener
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        myButton.setChecked(true);

        // CALL WHATEVER METHOD IS SUPPOSED TO BE CALLED WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED

    }
});
```